# If I reuse a puppeteer browser for too long, timeout errors keep occurring when accessing new URLs

Tags: puppeteer

I am using puppeteer in a docker container. I get URLs from the message queue, access them, and take screenshots. While the container is running for more than 8 hours, timeout errors keep occurring for new URLs. If I delete and recreate the docker container, it connects properly. I can’t find the cause and need help. Below is the related code.

```js
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

const queueName = 'browser';

let browser;

async function launchBrowser() {
    if (!browser) {
      browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ["--no-sandbox"],
      headless: true,
      executablePath: "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"});
    }
    return browser;
}

amqp.connect(mq_connection, (error0, connection) => {
  if (error0) {
    throw error0;
  }
  connection.createChannel((error1, channel) => {
    if (error1) {
      throw error1;
    }
    channel.assertQueue(queueName, {
      durable: false,
    });
    channel.prefetch(1);
    channel.assertQueue(outputQueueName, {
      durable: false,
    });
    channel.consume(queueName, async (msg) => {
      // Parse the message as JSON
      const message = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
      console.log(message)
      // Get the URL from the message
      const url = message.url;
      const msgId = message.id;
      const md5 =  message.md5;
      const time = message.time;
      const resultMsg = {"id": msgId, "time": time, "firstUrl": url, "md5": md5, "browserErrorMsg": "", "browserError":0}
      try{
        // Launch the browser if it is not already launched
        const browser = await launchBrowser();
        // Create a new page
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setViewport({
            ...
        });
        await page.setUserAgent("...")
        // Go to the URL
        const response = await page.goto(url, {timeout: 10000});

        if(!response){
            resultMsg["browserError"] = 1
            resultMsg["browserErrorMsg"] = "null response"
        } 
        else if (response.status() !== 200){
            resultMsg["browserError"] = 1
            resultMsg["browserErrorMsg"] = "not 200"
        }
        else {
            const headers = response.headers();
            contentType = headers['content-type']
            statusCode = response.status()

            if (!contentType.includes("text/html")) {
                resultMsg["browserError"] = 1
                resultMsg["browserErrorMsg"] = "not html"
            }
            else{
                ...                
                const content = await page.content()
                const contentPath = path.join(resultDir, "response.text")
                fs.writeFileSync(contentPath, content)

                // Take a screenshot and save it
                const screenshotPath = path.join(resultDir, "screenshot.png");
                await page.screenshot({ path: screenshotPath });
            }
        }

        // Close the page
        await page.close();
        
      } catch (err){
        resultMsg["browserError"] = 1
        resultMsg["browserErrorMsg"] = err.toString()
      }
      // Acknowledge the message
      channel.ack(msg);
      console.log(`Processed message: ${msg.content.toString()}`);
    });
  });
});
```